# ¿Cómo validar un carácter que no sea numero?

Tags: javascript, html

Hola chicos estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio de JavaScript, pero no consigo atinar a sacar la parte de validación del carácter para que no sea un número. Aquí el código.

Validar que ninguno de los caracteres de la palabra sea un número, avisando del error.

```
function comprobarPalabra() {
  var mensaje;

  expReg = /[a-zA-Z]\w+\w/;

  var palabra = prompt("Introduzca una palabra de más de 9 caracteres");

  if (!(expReg.test(palabra))) {
    mensaje = "La palabra debe contener un valor de más 8 caracteres";
  }
  if ((expReg.test(palabra))) {
    mensaje = "La palabra es -> &nbsp;" + palabra.toUpperCase();
  }

  document.getElementById("palabra").innerHTML = mensaje;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede ser una misma validación como la que ya tienes de tu regex, únicamente valida si un campo es numero y le cambias el mensaje.

```js
function comprobarPalabra() {
  var mensaje;

  expReg = /[a-zA-Z]\w+\w/;
  expRegNumeros = /[0-9]/;

  var palabra = prompt("Introduzca una palabra de más de 9 caracteres");

  if (!(expReg.test(palabra))) {
    mensaje = "La palabra debe contener un valor de más 8 caracteres";
  }
  if ((expReg.test(palabra))) {
    mensaje = "La palabra es -> &nbsp;" + palabra.toUpperCase();
  }
  if ((expRegNumeros.test(palabra))) {
    mensaje = "No debe contener Numeros";
  }

  document.getElementById("palabra").innerHTML = mensaje;
}

comprobarPalabra()
```

```html
<div id="palabra"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Eduardo Jaramillo Licea, me faltaba esa parte y no sabía como plantearla, así parece mas simple !

Answer (score 0):

Esto se puede hacer muy fácilmente

```js
let message = "H0l4"
let messageTwo = "Hola"

if( /\d/.test(message)){ //Usamos expresiones regulares para decir que queremos ver si tiene un número y el método 'test' para comprobarlo
  console.log("el mensaje tiene número")
} else {
  console.log("no tiene un número")
}

if( /\d/.test(messageTwo)){
  console.log("el mensaje 'dos' tiene número")
} else {
 console.log("mensaje 'dos 'no tiene un número")
}
```